# Annoyed ‘by’, ‘for’, ‘to’ or ‘because of’

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Let’s imagine few disciples of a priest have committed crimes by misusing their power and that makes the priest very annoyed. Now, which preposition should I use in the sentence below which describes the scenario?

“The priest is very annoyed (by/for/to/because of/something else) his disciples.”

Answer (score 1):

For me, it would either be written as past tense:

> The priest was very annoyed **by** his disciples.

Or, you would actually use "at" or "with", specifying the direction/object(s) of his annoyance.

> The priest is very annoyed **at** his disciples.
>
> The priest is very annoyed **with** his disciples.

You could also say (though I don't find this particularly idiomatic):

> The priest is very annoyed **because of** his disciples.

I do feel "because of" would be more idiomatic if it were said as:

> The priest is very annoyed *because of* **what** his disciples **did**.

Answer (score 0):

When X makes Y happen, X is the *agent* of Y.  *Y by X* expresses an agency relationship.  The verb form will be passive voice.

> I made her stop.  She was stopped by me.

*To* and *for* won't work.